# What's the corresponding term for the mouth?

Tags: expressions, metaphors

To wear blinkers or blinders is used metaphorically to mean choosing deliberately not to see or ignore the truth; to wear ear plugs refers to one voluntarily choosing not to listen. How about the mouth?

Can choosing to keep silent when one oughtn't be metaphorically referred to as **wearing a muzzle?**

Comment: But hey, eyes and ears and receptive sense organs, the mouth is a productive organ not a sense organ -- do not compare!

Comment: In my language there's the expression to put/apply henna onto one's mouth -meaning to keep deliberately silent when one shouldn't.

Comment: Though it originally means something slightly different (keeping your eyes/ears/mouth shut when you're _supposed_ to), it's quite common to use the phrase **see no evil, hear no evil, speak no evil** in the way you're asking for, too. That only applies to all three at once, though: if you just say _speak no evil_, it becomes more literal again. (Nowadays, arguably the most common way to write this is , which may or may not show up properly on this site.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some say that they're keeping their lips zipped where I'm from, but its more associated with secrets... But it can work. "He kept his lips sealed when he knew he ought to say something about... his manager?" What's the context? Either way, there's probably more creative ones. Clammed up is one...

Coming at the question at another angle, I don't think there's a popular metaphor mainly because the good ones are associated more with bondage and the like. Gagged, muzzled... Yeah, those can work but have a really ugly connotation, and I can't think of anything else that fits in the set.

Answer (score 8):

I think the figure of speech you're looking for is to **hold your tongue**.

> **hold one's tongue** ([TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hold+tongue))
>
> Fig. to refrain from speaking; to refrain from saying something unpleasant. I felt like scolding her, but I held my tongue. Hold your tongue, John. You can't talk to me that way!

Comment: "Bite your tongue" means "I hope what you just said isn't true", but sometimes it's used like "hold": "When my wife asked me how her new hairdo looked, I bit my tongue and smiled."

Comment: But this doesn't address OP's 'choosing to keep silent **when one oughtn't**'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Is there some reason you think it doesn't fit in that circumstance?  Often 'when one oughtn't' is when it would be unpleasant, so I believe it works just fine.

Comment: It might be a _commendable_ choice to 'hold one's tongue' on occasion. One would be doing right by holding one's tongue.

Answer (score 6):

Metaphors for keeping quiet are generally transitive, for example *muzzled* or *gagged*.

> The protestors were effectively gagged by the court order.
>   Opposition leaders accused him of muzzling the news media [example from [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/muzzle)]

The reason for this is probably because it's something one would not normally choose to do to oneself, unlike wearing earplugs for example.

Synonyms for *gag* listed by ODO include *mute,* which can also be an adjective and might be applied to people unable to speak through disability — so it's not necessarily the result of a transitive verb.

> He was mute about the changes to be made.

Comment: @ Andrew Leach actually I'm looking for a noun form corresponding to the mouth --that's why I suggested a muzzle or perhaps a seal but used in expressions to mean voluntarily acting dumb.

Comment: Yes. One of the purposes of my answer was to indicate that I don't believe there is such a metaphor in common use, if at all.

Comment: But this doesn't address OP's '**choosing** to keep silent **when one oughtn't'**.

Answer (score 2):

Wearing a muzzle could be used metaphorically, but the meaning would not be clear. To me it conveys the idea of being forced not to talk. Choosing to keep silent can be expressed as:

to [keep mum](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/keep+mum) or keep one's mouth shut:

> - refuse to talk or stop talking; fall silent; "The children shut up when their father approached"

also

to [button up](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/button+up) -  stop talking; fall silent;

*buttoned up*: taciturn; silent and somewhat tense

Answer (score 1):

One oft-used idiom for remaining silent is ["keeping your own counsel"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/keep-your-own-counsel) (Cambridge Dictionaries)

- to not say what your opinions are

Comment: But this doesn't address OP's 'choosing to keep silent **when one oughtn't**'.

Comment: The phrase, like many others quoted here, does not deal with explicitly with the "choosing", it covers the act of refraining from speaking (and thereby implicitly choosing). I don't think there are *any* phrases that cover the specific situation when one *should* talk but chooses not to, however 'keeping one's own counsel' has been frequently used in my experience to advise other's to refrain from talking when circumstances dictate that they normally would.

Comment: 'Keep stumm' carries a reasonable connotation of 'withhold evidence'.

Answer (score 1):

It was [explained](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/215831/98955) that you wouldn't choose to *muzzle* yourself. I don't think you would [*put a damper on*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+a+damper+on) your speech either. But there is [*self-censorship*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/self-censorship) when there is no external agency involved in the censoring. Whether figuratively speaking *to self-censor* would actually be about keeping silent when you *oughtn't* is another question altogether. It may not be very idiomatic but does showcase the *choice* the person makes and the muzzling effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking specifically for a mouth-oriented phrase that is not "muzzled" then ["tight-lipped"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tight-lipped?s=t) could be used, though it does not imply *complete and utter* silence:

> (Adj) 1. speaking very little; taciturn; close-mouthed.

Answer (score 0):

"Stifle yourself, Dingbat!" Archie to Edith Bunker, from *All In The Family* by Norman Lear, circa 1971.